# Suppose X is Binomial(3,1/2) and Y is Binomial(2,1/2). Let Z = 2X - 3Y. Assume X and Y are independent.

Tags: random-variables, binomial-distribution

Suppose X is Binomial(3,1/2) and Y is Binomial(2,1/2). Let Z = 2X - 3Y. Assume X and Y are independent.
What is the smallest value of Z?
What is the largest value of Z?
I am unsure on how you would calculate these two values. Also, how would you computer P(Z=1) by hand to get an exact fraction? I have simulated this and got approximately 0.19.

Comment: Can you at least answer: What is the smallest value of $X$? What is the largest value of $X$? What is the smallest value of $Y$? What is the largest value of $Y$?

Comment: Would the max be when the Probability is at its mean, so 1.5 for X and 1 for Y?

Comment: Henry is asking you the largest possible value $X$ could be, not what value has the highest probability.

Answer (score 2):

One simple straightforward way is to write down all $12$ possibiliteis for $(X,Y)$. $-6$ is the smallest and $+6$ is the largest value. $Z=1$ is possible only when $Y=1$ and $X=2$ so $P(Z=1)=\binom {3}{2} (\frac 1 2)^{3} \binom {2} {1} ((\frac 1 2)^{2}$.